# How to pass post values to webapi .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to post datetime into the below api. But it is not going through.

lastRefreshDateTime.Result is datetime

Below is the code I tried:

```
await client.PostAsync($"{_printApiUrl}pdf/GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs/${lastRefreshDateTime.Result}", content, cancellationToken);



 [Authorize]
    [Route("api/pdf/GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs/{lastRefreshDateTime}")]
    public void GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs([FromBody]List<UrlObject> urls,DateTime lastRefreshDateTime)
```

Comment: What is actually happening?

Comment: when the line await client.PostAsync($"{_printApiUrl}pdf/GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs/${lastRefreshDateTime.Result}", content, cancellationToken); is executed it is not calling the  public void GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs([FromBody]List<UrlObject> urls,DateTime lastRefreshDateTime) api

Comment: What is `lastRefreshDateTime`? Note I asked about `lastRefreshDateTime` and not `lastRefreshDateTime.Result`

Comment: it has object of datetime

Comment: var lastRefreshDateTime =  _contentManagement.GetLastRefreshDateTime(cancellationToken);

Comment: The call to `.Result` is suspect.  Don't assume which operation is failing, test and validate.  You're invoking `.Result` on the same line as `.PostAsync()`.  Separate them.  When you store the result of `.Result` in its own variable, what happens?

Comment: I tried the below code as well
DateTime test = lastRefreshDateTime.Result; await client.PostAsync($"{_printApiUrl}pdf/GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs/${test}", content, cancellationToken);

Comment: @HarshaMullangi You are most likely experiencing a deadlock by calling a blocking call `.Result` in an async function. you need to use `await`. `var lastRefreshDateTime = await _contentManagement.GetLastRefreshDateTime(cancellationToken);`

Comment: Then how do i do?

Comment: @HarshaMullangi: And when you tried that code, *what happened*?  When you output the value of `test`, what is that value at runtime?  Why are you calling `.Result` directly instead of using `await`?

Comment: I am getting a value like {1/13/2020 10:05:37 PM}

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely experiencing a deadlock by mixing a blocking call like `.Result` in an async function.

You need to use `await`.

```
var lastRefreshDateTime = await _contentManagement.GetLastRefreshDateTime(cancellationToken);
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Also note how the URI is generated using [$ - string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

```
var uri = $"{_printApiUrl}pdf/GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs/{lastRefreshDateTime}";
await client.PostAsync(uri, content, cancellationToken);
```

There was an errant `$` in the shown URI that would cause the date time to be malformed when posted.

Should also consider using a route constraint

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/pdf/GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs/{lastRefreshDateTime:datetime}")]
public void GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs(
    [FromBody]List<UrlObject> urls, 
    [FromRoute]DateTime lastRefreshDateTime
)
```

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)

Comment: The Problem is my method is void so i am not able to use await public void GenerateAndEmailZipOfPDFs(

Comment: @HarshaMullangi them have the method return `Task` or use an async event handler

Comment: @HarshaMullangi you say it is void yet still use `await client.PostAsync`

Comment: you say it is void yet still use await client.PostAsync : yes it works. but i want to send one more datetime variable and that i am unable to send

Comment: sorry i am adding inside a task. But still i am not able to call the api

Comment: Don't use `async void`. There's a handful of *specific* scenarios where that makes sense, but almost invariably your situation isn't one of them. In other words, if you should do that, you'll be well aware that you should and why. If you don't need a return, use just `Task`, not `void`.

Comment: @HarshaMullangi check updated answer.